# Summing up data that meets month range criteria in another column using formula?

Tags: excel

For example, if month is between 5 and 10 sum data from another column with rows that meet that month criteria.

The formula that I'm using for summer months:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($N$6:$N$77)<=10)*(MONTH($N$6:$N$77)>=5)*($I$6:$I$77))
```

returns the correct total.

The formula that I'm using on the same data set for winter months returns a "0".

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($N$6:$N$77)<=4)*(MONTH($N$6:$N$77)>=11)*($I$6:$I$77))
```

I'm doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for both.

Answer (score 0):

The month cannot be both *less than 5 AND greater than 10*. You need an **Or** and you are using an **And**.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($N$6:$N$77)<=4)+(MONTH($N$6:$N$77)>=11), $I$6:$I$77)
'alternate
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($N$6:$N$77)={1,2,3,4,11,12})*($I$6:$I$77))
```

The latter uses an array constant of applicable month ordinals and may be easier to maintain and modify for other periods. Those formulas does not actually require CSE.